# HashMap with synchronized block:

Tags: java, hashmap, synchronized

After these posts 
[Locking value objects of a ConcurrentHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485630/locking-value-objects-of-a-concurrenthashmap/38488774#38488774)

[ConcurrentHashMap: how to replace the value of an entry only if the current value is smalle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473358/concurrenthashmap-how-to-replace-the-value-of-an-entry-only-if-the-current-valu/38473574?noredirect=1#comment64375962_38473574)

[Can we use Synchronized for each entry instead of ConcurrentHashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470322/can-we-use-synchronized-for-each-entry-instead-of-concurrenthashmap/38470603?noredirect=1#comment64366014_38470603)

And spending so much time, I think I should give up on concurrency (at least for now) and forget entry locking. It is too error-prone. Several times I came up with a solution, but again I found a bug.

So, if I want to scarify concurrency, and jut have a correct program, I think the easiest what is locking the whole hash table. So what is the best way to do that. I have 6 hash tables.  One solution is using 6 HashMaps and whenever I want to do something use synchronized block. Is it OK, or I need to use ConcurrenHashMap? Note that I am using synchronized block.

Comment: I read somewhere that we you are writing a multithreaded program you should not use HashMap AT ALL. So my question is, even if I use synchronized whenever I what to do anything with that, using HashMap is a problem? I am insisting on using HashMap, because I think it has better performance than ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: What purpose does a hashmap with synchronized block solve? as you already added synchronized, performance is gonna be slow anyways.

Comment: I know. But which one is better? Synchronized + HashMap or Synchronized + ConcurrentHashMap. 

Note That I need use synchronized anyway, even if I use ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: are you sure SynchronizedHashMap doesn't solve your problem? Locks are at object level in this type of map.

Comment: The problem is some of my hash maps has value with type hash map or list,... When I access get a key, OK the get operation is synchronized or whatever, but it is possible that two thread work on the inner hashmap (the value).

Comment: You haven't shared any code regarding the problem you're trying to solve. If you shared some code and specified your requirements, this question could perhaps be answerable.